# Apache Airflow Webserver error says SSL key file does not exist, even though there is one there

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ssl, airflow

I am very new to SSL, certificates, and keys, so I appreciate any help and recognize I'm probably making a boneheaded mistake.

I'm running a Docker Swarm on three internal CentOS 7 servers. The Swarm deploys, in part, a custom Docker image for running Apache Airflow 1.10.0 (planning to upgrade to 1.10.1 soon). The image starts `FROM python:3.5-slim`, which is based on Ubuntu.

I followed [this guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html) to generate a self-signed CA, certs, and keys. I think this is appropriate for my use case because the servers are on an internal network and the Airflow webserver will only be accessed by members of my team while they're on site or using a VPN.

Part of the `docker-compose.yml` is as follows in order to give the containers access to the cert and key:

```
version: 3.5
    services:
        [...]
    webserver:
        [...]
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /root/ca/intermediate/certs
              target: /usr/local/airflow/intermediate/certs
            - type: bind
              source: /root/ca/intermediate/private
              target: /usr/local/airflow/intermediate/private
```

I changed the owner of the files from within the containers to the `airflow` user in the container, so that the application can read them.

The relevant `airflow.cfg` is as follows:

```
[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:443
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
web_server_port = 443
web_server_ssl_cert = /usr/local/airflow/intermediate/certs/my_server.cert.pem
web_server_ssl_key = /usr/local/airflow/intermediate/private/my_server.key.pem
```

The `.cert.pem` and `.key.pem` files are the same on all three servers. I did this because I suspect the Docker Swarm routing mesh will expect uniformity across the servers. (Is this a vulnerability or otherwise a mistake?)

The Dockerfile also `EXPOSE`s port `443`.

However, this is the error I get whenever the webserver attempts to start:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 [2018-11-29 19:43:10 +0000] [36] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
     sys.exit(run())
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
     sys.exit(run())
     super(Application, self).run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
     Arbiter(self).run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 199, in run
     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
     self.start()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 157, in start
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
     self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 162, in create_sockets
     super(Application, self).run()
     raise ValueError('keyfile "%s" does not exist' % conf.keyfile)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
     Arbiter(self).run()
 ValueError: keyfile "/usr/local/airflow/intermediate/private/my_server.key.pem" does not exist
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 199, in run
     self.start()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 157, in start
     self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 162, in create_sockets
     raise ValueError('keyfile "%s" does not exist' % conf.keyfile)
 ValueError: keyfile "/usr/local/airflow/intermediate/private/my_server.key.pem" does not exist
```

So my question is, how do I get Airflow to recognize the SSL key and certificate in an appropriate way? The Airflow [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ssl) on the subject is pretty terse.

I hope I've provided enough context -- happy to offer more if that helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Double check the permissions too. Normally a keyfile should have a small set of permissions (not being world readable for example) and hence your process needs to run under appropriate account to be able to read it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, I thought that might be an issue too. But the my_server.cert.pem and my_server.key.pem are both r--r--r--.

Comment: Then the computer really think the file does not exist. What does `cat /usr/local/airflow/intermediate/private/my_server.key.pem` output?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It `cat`s out the RSA Private Key as expected.

Comment: This [stackoverflow's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853316/nginx-ssl-no-such-file-or-directory-with-docker#answer-52120734) solved my issue, I had the same error than you

Answer (score -2):

This solved
chmod 777 file.key
chmod 777 file.crt

luego cambia la
base_url = https://localhost:443